# how to get the form values when i click on submit in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch

i new to sencha touch,and i created a login form which accepts user id and password and a login button,so when i click on login button i should get the user id value as a alert.and the code is,

```
Ext.setup ({
onReady: function () {

    var myform=new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    id:'form',
    fullscreen:true,
    standardSubmit:true,
    dockedItems:[{
    Dock:'top',
    xtype:'toolbar',
    height:40,
    title:'Tool Bar',
    id:'login',
    }
    ],
    items:[{
 xtype:'textfield',
 name:'id',

 width:'50%',
 align:'center',
 label:'User Id'
 },
 {
 xtype:'textfield',
 name:'pwd',
 id:'pwd',
 width:'50%',
 align:'center',
 label:'Password'
 },

 {
  xtype:'button',
  ui:'round',
  width:'50%',
  text:'Login',
  align:'center',
  handler:function()
  {
    gettingvalues();/* var fields = form.getValues();
    console.log(fields['name']); */

  }
 }
 ],

    });

    gettingvalues=function()
    {
      var fields=myform.getValues();
      Ext.Msg.alert(fields['id'].getValue()); 
    }


}
```

});

But am not getting any value in alert,what i have to do.
and after that i want to send those values to our local server which requires id and password,it will be in the format of...
**oururl?action=login&id=xyz&pwd=xyz**,
in this it will accepts and returns the response,so for that what i have to write,
please let me know as soon as possible.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can get form values via their name attribute, like this:

```
{
  xtype:'button',
  ui:'round',
  width:'50%',
  text:'Login',
  align:'center',
  handler:function()
  {
     var form = myForm.getValues();
     console.log('Form Object: ' + form);
     console.log('User ID Field: ' + form.id);
     console.log('Password Field: ' + form.pwd);         
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
var fields=myform.getValues();
Ext.Msg.alert(fields['id']);
```

do you get any javascript errors?